# Hacking WordPress site

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem that a series of files are created and most importantly it changes the index page. No matter how many files I completely delete, new Wi-Fis are created with new names. Can anyone guide?
Please see the photos I have attached
[image]

[image]

I also delete all the files from trash, and I also deleted the wp-admin and wp-includes folders and downloaded again, but the problem is still not solved. Usually, when I clean, this problem returns after two days.

Comment: This is a security problem, not a programming problem. You need to delete everything -- everything -- in your web site, restore it from a backup before you were pwned, and change all the WordPress passwords for privileged accounts.  For help deleting everything, you may want to ask your hosting provider.

Comment: Take full website backup and then overwrite wordpress source code to your website. so, infected fill will overwrite with original code. Then you have to update all plugin and wordpress and also add security plugin to stop this type of attack in future.